# sed: delete everything that starts with $p, but not just $p

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to find a sed command that will delete every instance of a wrod that begins with another word, but not the word itself. So if I have

```
aardvark
aardvarky
aardvarkiest
```

I want to delete aardvarky and aardvarkiest, but not aardvark.

I tried

```
sed -n  "/^$p.*/ d"
```

hoping to do some kind of regex that meant starting with $p and then some characters *, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Because - extremely basic! - `*` means *zero* or more characters? Try `+`.

Comment: and you should take care of the  substitution.

Comment: word is know before running your script (and thus specific) or it will remove any word that are an extension of one already in the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deletes all lines that start with `$p` and have at least one more character:

```
$ sed "/^$p./d" file
aardvark
```

To change the file in place, use the `-i` option.  With GNU sed:

```
sed -i "/^$p./d" file
```

With BSD (OSX) sed:

```
sed -i "" "/^$p./d" file
```

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
sed -n  "/^$p.*/ d"
```

This command will print nothing: `-n` means print nothing unless explicitly asked to and there is no command with an explicit print (`p`).

Further, `*` means zero or move of the preceding character.  Thus, `$p.*` matches `$p` also.

We could use:

```
$ sed "/^$p.\+/d" file
aardvark
```

`\+` means one or more of the preceding character.  However, the `\+` is not useful because any line that matches `^$p.\+` also matches the simpler `^$p.` (and vice versa).

#### Warning

The use of shell variables in sed commands is potentially dangerous.  As an example, the following writes a file to the current directory:

```
p=$'a/w hi.there\n/'; sed "/^$p.\+/d" file
```

A shell variable should not be used in a sed command unless the shell variable is created by code that is trusted.

Comment: Perfect for output, but how do I make the deletion in the original file? Currently it outputs just aardvark, but the file itself still contains all three words. Thank you

Comment: To change the file in-place, use sed's `-i` option.  I added an example of this to the answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot! Also found that -i needs to be -i.bak on osx in case that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

use grep as below to keep all lines except aardvark

```
grep -v -w 'aardvark' file
```

if you want to delete everything except aardvark:

```
grep -w aardvark file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i /^'"$word"'\B/d' file
```

This deletes any line that begins with `$word` but does not end on a word boundary.